# want to use ubuntu desktop os on a server providing ubuntu use just by login?

Tags: legal

To Ubuntu Team

I would like to provide Ubuntu desktop OS directly in the browser, if this is not possible I will find an alternate way of doing it.  As students in India are using less Ubuntu I want to encourage the habit of using Ubuntu in their routine.  Free Ubuntu DVDs were given but few students really tried it and are not using it unless it is compulsory.

My only question is: Am  I (legally) allowed to try to do it?

Comment: I believe Ubuntu is open source, and you can try alternate methods of providing it to the desktop of your students.  I do not know of a method for doing this, however.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the ubuntu tour?  It's provided straight from Canonical.  It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but check it out.

http://www.ubuntu.com/tour/en/#